# Finding the most visited place at a particular time in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a user's table that has info about user_id, places user purchased tickets, and the time user had purchased the ticket.

**Users:**

```
|------------|-------------|----------------------|
|  user_id   |  place      | purchase_time        |
|------------|-------------|----------------------|
|     1      |  New York   | 2021-11-27:17:00:21  |
|     1      |  Chicago    | 2021-11-25:19:00:21  |
|     1      |  Chicago    | 2021-11-23:03:00:21  |
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-21:07:00:21  |
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-19:12:00:21  |
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-17:00:00:21  |
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-15:23:00:21  |
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-12:21:00:21  |
|     2      |  Chicago    | 2021-09-25:01:00:21  |
|     2      |  Milwaukee  | 2021-09-24:02:00:21  |
|     2      |  Milwaukee  | 2021-09-23:03:00:21  |
|     2      |  New York   | 2021-09-22:19:00:21  |
|     2      |  Chicago    | 2021-09-21:01:00:21  |
|     3      |  Milwaukee  | 2021-10-27:12:31:21  |
|     3      |  Washington | 2021-10-24:07:01:23  |
|     3      |  Chicago    | 2021-10-21:01:78:89  |
|------------|-------------|----------------------|
```

I want to add a new column that shows the user's most visited place at the time of purchasing ticket. The table would like (Snowflake):

```
|------------|-------------|----------------------|---------------------|
|  user_id   |  place      | purchase_time        | most_visited_place  |
|------------|-------------|----------------------|---------------------|
|     1      |  New York   | 2021-11-27:17:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Chicago    | 2021-11-25:19:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Chicago    | 2021-11-23:03:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-21:07:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-19:12:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-17:00:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-15:23:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     1      |  Washington | 2021-11-12:21:00:21  |    Washington       | <--- Washington, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     2      |  Chicago    | 2021-09-21:01:00:25  |    Chicago          | <-- tie, break. Both Chicago and Milwaukee were most visited then take the recent most visited
|     2      |  Milwaukee  | 2021-09-21:02:00:24  |    Milwaukee        | <--- Milwaukee, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     2      |  Milwaukee  | 2021-09-21:03:00:23  |    Milwaukee        | <--- Milwaukee, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     2      |  New York   | 2021-09-21:19:00:22  |    New York         | <-- tie, break. Both Chicago and New York were most visited then take the recent most visited
|     2      |  Chicago    | 2021-09-21:01:00:21  |    Chicago          | <--- Chicago, because at purchase_time This place was most visited by the user
|     3      |  Milwaukee  | 2021-10-27:12:31:21  |    Milwaukee        |
|     3      |  Washington | 2021-10-24:07:01:23  |    Washington       |
|     3      |  Chicago    | 2021-10-21:01:78:89  |    Chicago          |
|------------|-------------|----------------------|---------------------|
```

Comment: You appear to have added 2 identical tables to your question. Please update your question to show the results you want to achieve

Comment: @NickW To the first table (```Users```), I want to add a new field ```most_visited_place``` based on the user's most places visited

Comment: You may try to use [`mode`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/mode.html#syntax) window function, that may process `varchar` also. But as long as I have no access to the Snowflake platform, I didn't tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [WINDOW](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#examples) version of COUNT to get the "prior rows count" and then join to all the prior counted rows, and filter out the "best" via a [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)

```
WITH prior_user AS (
    SELECT 
        user_id,
        place,
        purchase_time,
        COUNT(place) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, place ORDER BY purchase_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS place_count
    FROM users
)
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    u.place,
    u.purchase_time,
    p.place AS most_visited_place
FROM users u
JOIN prior_user p
    ON u.user_id = p.user_id AND u.purchase_time >= p.purchase_time
QUALIFY row_number() OVER (partition by u.user_id, u.purchase_time ORDER BY place_count DESC, p.purchase_time DESC) = 1
```

*this sql has not been run.

Comment: What is order by ```o``` in line 6?

Comment: haha, cut in paste typo, will fix

Comment: also the `COUNT(PLACE)` could also just be a `ROW_NUMBER()` because `place` is in the PARTITON BY..

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant approach for this business logic answer. Is it possible to add another field ```previous_most_visited_place``` to the above table.

Comment: as in the "prior to this" best? you can take the `1,2` but then you need to add another layer to lag to from the 1st get the 2nd, and then filter out the 2nd.

Comment: what is ```1,2```? can you please update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239863/discussion-between-simeon-pilgrim-and-r0bert).

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a `lateral` join in Snowflake. The use of `distinct` is kind of ugly but I think you could substitute that for a `qualify` and possibly even get a better plan. I'd be curious to see if this is equivalent to the other answer from an execution standpoint.

```
select *
from Users u, lateral (
    select distinct first_value(place) over ()
        order by count(*) desc, max(u2.purchase_time) desc) as most_visited_place
    from Users u2
    where u2.user_id = u.user_id and u2.purchase_time <= u.purchase_time
    group by place
    --qualify row_number() over (order by u2.user_id) = 1 
) as mr
order by user_id, purchase_time desc
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02784df13affab8027f7b052ad942d70

Comment: When I tried the above query in snowflake, getting an error ```syntax error line 2 at position 34 unexpected 'lateral'```

Comment: @R0bert Looks like Snowflake wants a comma before `lateral`.